# Invalid CSS after "...rder-bottom: 0;": expected "

Tags: css, gulp, sass

Получаю такую ошибку, при сборке проекта, на этапе компиляции css из sass. 
Никак не пойму что это может означать ?

> [21:26:31] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp]
>   app\libs\bootstrap\bootstrap.sass Error: Invalid CSS after
>   "...rder-bottom: 0;": expected "}", was "+ .panel-collapse >"
>           on line 5535 of app/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.sass
>
> > > ```
> > > border-bottom: 0;    ----------------------^
> > > ```

пример строки из файла, на который ругается:

```
5534      .panel-heading
5535        border-bottom: 0
5536        + .panel-collapse >
5537        .panel-body, .list-group
5538          border-top: 1px solid #ddd
```

Upd:

сделал как сказал Vadizar, ошибка пропала. Собирается ок. Но редактор ругается теперь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не поставили табуляцию перед `.panel-body, .list-group`:

```
   .panel-heading
        border-bottom: 0
        + .panel-collapse >
            .panel-body, .list-group
                border-top: 1px solid #ddd
```

Comment: не похоже, когда ставлю табуляции редактор ругается на -  .list-group - End of line expect

Comment: сообщение об ошибке пропало, собирается нормально

Comment: Я поставил как написал и скомпилировалось. Когда поставил ваш пример, поругалось на туже строку.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ушел `end of line expected` нужно сделать так:

```
.panel-heading
    border-bottom: 0
    + .panel-collapse
        >.panel-body,  >.list-group
            border-top: 1px solid #ddd
```

Ошибка возникает, когда логически строка должна закончиться, но IDE находит еще какие-либо символы в ней.